Flutter Appsflyter deeplink issue: No pre-install link matched for this device
I have set a deeplink in AppsFlyer. When the app is running and a user clicks on the link, all the relevant data and parameters are retrieved correctly using the method "onDeepLinking()".
However, when the app is not installed and a user clicks on the link, it navigates to the Appstore to install the app. After installing the app, the link does not work and gives an error.
Link: https://<MY CUSTOM GENERATED LINK>?deep_link_value=amit

Response I am getting:
{
  "scheme": "-----------",
  "request_ip_version": "IP_V4",
  "is_deferred": false,
  "host": "google",
  "link": "----------://google/link/?request_ip_version=IP%5FV4&match_message=No%20pre%2Dinstall%20link%20matched%20for%20this%20device%2E",
  "path": "/link",
  "match_message": "No pre-install link matched for this device."
}

I am not getting my passed parameters. Following is my setup for AppsFlyer.
final AppsFlyerOptions options = AppsFlyerOptions(
        afDevKey: '<My Development key>',
        //For iOS app id is required
        appId: '<My App id for iOS>',
        timeToWaitForATTUserAuthorization: 15,
        manualStart: false,
      );
      _appsflyerSdk = AppsflyerSdk(options);

      await _appsflyerSdk.initSdk(
        registerOnDeepLinkingCallback: true,
        registerConversionDataCallback: true,
        registerOnAppOpenAttributionCallback: true,
      );

      _appsflyerSdk.startSDK();

      _appsflyerSdk.onAppOpenAttribution((res) {
        print('res: $res');
      });

      _appsflyerSdk.onInstallConversionData((res) {
        print('res: $res');
      });

      _appsflyerSdk.onDeepLinking((DeepLinkResult res) {
        print('res: ${res.toJson()}');
      });


Ive got same problem, and the only custom value that it accepts is literally "deep_link_value"(ive tryed with af_sub too).
In my case, the problem was generating an inviteLink ( which is a deeplink made programatically with method generateInviteLink) and in the custom params (AppsFlyerInviteLinkParams) specify this key with whatever value, in my case a referral code.
In your case, i think you have to specify this value in the fourth step of the links creation process of your OneLinkManagement dashboard.
Hope it helps, im just trying to understand the flutter documentation of this sdk too...
